# NSCache with NSDiscardableContent or NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, nscache

Currently, I'm using `NSCache` to store data for my app. I can always retrieve that data again from the server, so it is not a problem if I eventually lose the data, that's why I'm using `NSCache`.

The problem is that every time my app enters background `NSCache` evicts data. I don't want it to evict data unless it is really necessary for memory improvement or if the object reaches its limits.

I don't want to switch to `NSDictionary` and get my app killed on the background if it uses too much memory. I could subclass `NSDictionary` and make it clear itself when needed or when getting memory warnings, but I guess this would be a lot of work.

I read around and found a few suggestions to use `NSCache` with `NSDiscardableContent` protocol, but didn't really found any sample code of implementation. I'm not even sure if this would be the best approach to my case.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

I found [this code](https://github.com/nicklockwood/OSCache) in github which gives me the expected result. Therefore, it doesn't use the `NSDiscardableContent` and I cannot identify what is going on that it doesn't remove objects in case app enters background state. I guess his method `- (void)cleanUp` is called every time `NSCache` will remove objects and there he only proceeds if object has reached its limit or received memory warning.

Anyway, I'm not a fan of using third party codes, so if anyone can help me mimic this behavior would be a great help.

Comment: Have you find any proper solution for this ?